# How to determine that the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\arctan(e^{-n})$ is convergent by using ratio test?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

How to determine that the series
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\arctan(e^{-n})$$
is convergent by using ratio test?

I tried to compute the ratio of
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\arctan(e^{-n-1})}{\arctan(e^{-n})}$$
But I do not know what is the result of that...

Comment: Hint: l'Hopital

Comment: Use the Maclaurin series for arctan.

Comment: It’s not hard if you know that $$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\arctan x}{x}=1.$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you able to use that for small positive $x$, $\frac{1}{2}x<\arctan(x)<x$?

If so, then $$0<\frac{\arctan(e^{-n-1})}{\arctan(e^{-n})}<\frac{e^{-n-1}}{\arctan(e^{-n})}<\frac{e^{-n-1}}{\frac12e^{-n}}=\frac{2}{e}<1$$